# Microsoft MFC library is not compatible with the C++ 20 Version? It generates errors during compilation

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, mfc, c++20

I use this setting in MS Visual C++ ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20); But when doing so on a Microsoft MFC library coded program the compiler produces errors on the MFC library. But still compiles and builds fine. Very strange.

[list of errors when compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEzX8.png)

However compiling with ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17) gives no errors, but I cannot use certain member functions of the map type such as map.contains(item)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try Clean & Rebuild the  solution. Which configuration? Debug? Release?

Comment: `/std:c++20` implicitly sets [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance). That's what's causing the errors/warnings. As a temporary workaround, try setting `/permissive` alongside `/std:c++20`. MFC cannot compile in conformance mode, and there's no tractable way to initiate change.

Comment: @IInspectable I just built a wizard created MFC MDI application with `/permissive-` and `/std:c++20` with Visual Studio 17.8.0 with out any issues.

Comment: Right, I didn't look at the screenshot. It lists `Exxxx` errors. Those are IntelliSense errors. They mean nothing. IntelliSense uses the EDG compiler frontend, which is distinctly different from MSVC's. Actual compiler errors use `Cxxxx` codes. I'm still confident in my assessment that MFC cannot compile in conformance mode for any real-world application.

Comment: Both in Debug and and Release the code compiles and links to a executable program. And is "runnable" . However the errors are there as seen in the picture. When switching back to C++17 no errors, but map.contains(fld) is ofcourse not there as it is a C++20 feature...

Comment: Clean and Rebuild do not solve the problem

Comment: Whne using C++20 the command line is like this: /JMC /Yu"pch.h" /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /std:c17 /Gd /MDd /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\MFCApplication1.pch" /diagnostics:column

Comment: Conformace mode = Default , question is now is Default: permissive- or permissive

Comment: Have tested with C++20 and /permissive and the errors are gone. So IInspectable you were right!

Comment: @RuudvanEijken which version of Visual Studio 2022 do you use?